# Imgur Api to Upload Photo

Tags: java, oauth, signature, imgur

I am trying to upload photos into imgur using its API's through oAUth.
I have been able to get the access token from imgur (after authorizing and authenticating), but when i try to use this access token to upload the images i am getting 401 error.

I suspect problems with my signature, being sent during the upload request.
PFB the Basestring and Key i am using to get the signature.

```
String signatureBaseString = "POST&" + 
    URLEncoder.encode(UploadURL, "UTF-8")+ 
   "&"+"oauth_consumer_key%3D"+ URLEncoder.encode(TwitterClientID, "UTF-8")+ 
   "%26oauth_nonce%3D"+ URLEncoder.encode(timestamp, "UTF-8")+ 
   "%26oauth_signature_method%3D"+ URLEncoder.encode("HMAC-SHA1", "UTF-8")+ 
   "%26oauth_timestamp%3D"+ URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(timestamp), "UTF-8")+ 
   "%26oauth_token%3D"+ URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "UTF-8")+ 
   "%26oauth_version%3D" + URLEncoder.encode("1.0", "UTF-8");


  String signingKey = TwitterClientSecret +"&"+accesstokenSecrate;
```

Is there anything that i am missing with respect to Signature ?